# pynput listener crashes code when implemented

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm very new to python and I don't know why but my code keeps crashing when I implement the listener specifically at the
`with Listener(on_press=press) as listener: listener.join()`   and when it crashes it doesn't give me a error message
here's the entirety of my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.constants import LEFT, N, NE, NW, W
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import time
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
from pynput.keyboard import Listener
self = tk.Tk()
self.title('Key spammer')
self.iconbitmap("D:\Vs code repos\Key spammer\keyboard-icon.ico")

#Set the geometry of frame
self.geometry("350x550")
self.resizable(False, False)

#Button exit function
def exit_prog():
    exit()

def press(key):
    print(key)

#press interval
self.grid_rowconfigure(20, weight=1)
self.grid_columnconfigure(20, weight=1)

labelframe = ttk.Labelframe(self,text= "Press interval")
labelframe.grid(row=1, column=0, padx= 25, sticky=N)

class Lotfi(ttk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        self.var = tk.StringVar()
        ttk.Entry.__init__(self, master, textvariable=self.var, **kwargs)
        self.old_value = ''
        self.var.trace('w', self.check)
        self.get, self.set = self.var.get, self.var.set

    def check(self, *args):
        if self.get().isdigit(): 
            # the current value is only digits; allow this
            self.old_value = self.get()
        else:
            # there's non-digit characters in the input; reject this 
            self.set(self.old_value)

#Entry interval
hoursentry = Lotfi(labelframe, width= 10)
hoursentry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx= 5, pady= 10)
hoursentry.insert(0, '0')
hourslabel = ttk.Label(labelframe, text= "hours")
hourslabel.grid(row=1, column=2)
minutesentry = Lotfi(labelframe, width= 10)
minutesentry.grid(row=1, column=3)
minutesentry.insert(0, '0')
minuteslabel = ttk.Label(labelframe, text= "mins")
minuteslabel.grid(row=1, column=4)
secondsentry = Lotfi(labelframe, width= 10)
secondsentry.grid(row=1, column=5)
secondsentry.insert(0, '0')
secondeslabel = ttk.Label(labelframe, text= "secs")
secondeslabel.grid(row=1, column=6)

labelframekey = ttk.Labelframe(self,text= "Key options")
labelframekey.grid(row=2, column=0, padx= 25, pady= 25, sticky=NW)
#labelframekey.pack(side= LEFT)

keypress = ttk.Label(labelframekey, text= "Key pressed", font= 10)
keypress.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky= N)

with Listener(on_press=press) as listener:
    listener.join()    
class Keyreg(ttk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        self.var = tk.StringVar()
        ttk.Entry.__init__(self, master, textvariable=self.var, **kwargs)
        self.old_value = ''
        self.var.trace('w', self.check)
        self.get, self.set = self.var.get, self.var.set

    def check(self, *args):
        if press: 
            self.set(self.old_value)

#Keyreg = Keyreg(labelframekey, width= 10)
#keyreg.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky= N)
'''
#Creation of Option buttons
button = ttk.Button(self, text = 'Exit', command = exit_prog, width = 25)
button.grid(row=2, column=1,padx= 5, ipadx=15, ipady=10)
button2 = ttk.Button(self, text = 'Exit', command = exit_prog, width = 25)
button2.grid(row=2, column=2, ipadx=15, ipady=10)
button3 = ttk.Button(self, text = 'Exit', command = exit_prog, width = 25)
button3.grid(row=3, column=1, ipadx=15, ipady=10)
button4 = ttk.Button(self, text = 'Exit', command = exit_prog, width = 25)
button4.grid(row=3, column=2, ipadx=15, ipady=10)
'''
#Top menu for keybinds

tk.mainloop()
```

I tried to figure out the problem myself but when i imported it to another tab and used multiple different methods it still never crashed on  those test

Please help me

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: there is good rule to put all `classes` directly after `import` and next all `functions`, and later rest of code (starting at `self = tk.Tk()`). More in [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: if you want to check `if press` then it is wrong because in your code `press` is a function, not variable - your `press()` should rather assign value to global variable and tkitner should check this global variable - or maybe listener should runs `Keyreg.check` instead of `press`

Comment: I don't understand what you wnat to do with `pyinput`. If you want to get key in tkinter window then you could use `root.bind('<Key>', press)`. Or `root.bind('<KeyPress>', press)` `root.bind('<KeyRelease>', press)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't show full error message so I don't know what is your real problem but I see one problem.

Code

```
with Listener(on_press=press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

runs code which waits for the end of `listener` and it stops rest of code

if you want to run it at the same time as `tkinter` then you should run as

```
with Listener(on_press=press) as listener:

    tk.mainloop()

    listener.join()
```

or more similar to `threading` (which is used by `listener`)

```
listener = Listener(on_press=press)
listener.start()

tk.mainloop()

listener.join()
```